# Select the complete bar of stacked bar chart D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

[![enter image description here][1]][1][![enter image description here][2]][2]

I need to highlight complete bar not one part of bar. 
on click of bar, I am trying to highlight the bar but it is not highlighting complete bar as shown in the above image.Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
.on('click', function(d) {
  d3.select(lastClicked).style('filter', '');


  var defs = d3.select('defs');
  var filter = defs.append("filter")
    .attr("id", "drop-shadow")
    .attr("height", "200%");

  d3.select(this).style("filter", "url(#drop-shadow)"); //To highlight the bar

  lastClicked = this;
  if (typeof(eventHandler) == "function")
    eventHandler(d);
});
```

Comment: Can you provide fiddle, where this problem will be reproduced?

Comment: It's hard to tell from an image -- but you may be able to select `this.parent` (if all the stacked bars for a given x-value are in a group) and apply the drop-shadow style to all of its children...

Comment: Thanks SteveR..we need use this.parentElement to select child elements. But what i expected is to select whole bar (if you click any part of the bar).Please find image (expected)

Comment: Could you please add a fiddle/plunkr real quick? It'd be easier to achieve the expected result.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/f0r5w7a1/

Comment: Hi shashank, I tried to reproduce issue but not able reproduce exactly. onclick of bar, it's adding white color to the particular part. In this case just want apply white color to the whole bar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a unique class to the rectangles in a single bar using data index as shown below. On clicking of the rect, this new class can be used for selection and highlight.

```
rects.attr("class", function(d, i) {
     return "rect" + i;
  })
  .on('click', function(d) {
    d3.selectAll(".highlighted")
      .style('filter', '')
      .classed("highlighted", false);

    d3.selectAll("." + d3.select(this).attr("class"))
      .style("filter", "url(#drop-shadow)")
      .classed("highlighted", true);
  });
```

```js
var svgWidth = 900,
  lastClicked
svgHeight = 500;

var margin = {
    top: 20,
    right: 50,
    bottom: 30,
    left: 20
  },
  svgWidth = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
  svgHeight = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;


data = [
  [{
    x: 1,
    y: 40
  }, {
    x: 2,
    y: 43
  }, {
    x: 3,
    y: 12
  }, {
    x: 4,
    y: 60
  }, {
    x: 5,
    y: 63
  }, {
    x: 6,
    y: 23
  }],
  [{
    x: 1,
    y: 12
  }, {
    x: 2,
    y: 5
  }, {
    x: 3,
    y: 23
  }, {
    x: 4,
    y: 18
  }, {
    x: 5,
    y: 73
  }, {
    x: 6,
    y: 27
  }],
  [{
    x: 1,
    y: 60
  }, {
    x: 2,
    y: 49
  }, {
    x: 3,
    y: 16
  }, {
    x: 4,
    y: 20
  }, {
    x: 5,
    y: 92
  }, {
    x: 6,
    y: 20
  }]
]

stack = d3.layout.stack()
layers = stack(data)

//colour scale
var c10 = d3.scale.category10();

//see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37688982/nesting-d3-max-with-array-of-arrays/37689132?noredirect=1#comment62916776_37689132
//for details on the logic behind this
max_y = d3.max(layers, function(d) {
  return d3.max(d, function(d) {
    return d.y0 + d.y;
  });
})

var yScale = d3.scale.linear()
  .domain([0, max_y])
  .range([svgHeight, 0]);

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
  .ticks(5)
  .scale(yScale)
  .orient("right");


var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr("width", svgWidth + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr("height", svgHeight + margin.top + margin.bottom);

var defs = d3.select('defs');
var filter = defs.append("filter")
  .attr("id", "drop-shadow")
  .attr("height", "200%");
filter.append("feGaussianBlur")
  .attr("in", "SourceAlpha")
  .attr("stdDeviation", 3)
  .attr("result", "blur");
filter.append("feOffset")
  .attr("in", "blur")
  .attr("dx", 3)
  .attr("dy", 3)
  .attr("result", "offsetBlur");

var feMerge = filter.append("feMerge");
feMerge.append("feMergeNode")
  .attr("in", "offsetBlur")
feMerge.append("feMergeNode")
  .attr("in", "SourceGraphic");

var groups = svg.selectAll("g")
  .data(layers)
  .enter()
  .append("g")
  .style("fill", function(d, i) {
    return c10(i)
  });

var rects = groups.selectAll("rect")
  .data(function(d) {
    return d
  })
  .enter()
  .append("rect")
  .attr("class", function(d, i) {
    return "rect" + i;
  })
  .attr("x", function(d) {
    return (d.x * 100) + 70
  })
  .attr("y", function(d) {
    return yScale(d.y0 + d.y)
  })
  .attr("width", 100)
  .attr("height", function(d) {
    return yScale(d.y0) - yScale(d.y + d.y0)
  })
  .on('click', function(d) {
    d3.selectAll(".highlighted")
      .style('filter', '')
      .classed("highlighted", false);

    d3.selectAll("." + d3.select(this).attr("class"))
      .style("filter", "url(#drop-shadow)")
      .classed("highlighted", true);
  });
  
//add y axis
svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "y axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + (svgWidth - 100) + ",0)")
  .call(yAxis)
  .style("stroke", "black");
```

```css
.axis text {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}

.axis line,
.axis path {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```